# Python module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime_CAPI'

Tags: python, numpy, api, python-datetime

I need to run numpy in an embedded system that has an ARM SoC, so I cross-compiled Python 3.8.10 and Numpy using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc. Then I copied both executables and libraries to the embedded system. But when I try to import numpy I get the following error:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime_CAPI'
```

So I checked the attributes of datetime:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dir(dt)
['MAXYEAR', 'MINYEAR', '_DAYNAMES', '_DAYS_BEFORE_MONTH', '_DAYS_IN_MONTH', '_DI100Y', '_DI400Y', '_DI4Y', 
'_EPOCH', '_MAXORDINAL', '_MONTHNAMES', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', 
'__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_build_struct_time', '_check_date_fields', '_check_int_field', '
_check_time_fields', '_check_tzinfo_arg', '_check_tzname', '_check_utc_offset', '_cmp', '_cmperror', 
'_date_class', '_days_before_month', '_days_before_year', '_days_in_month', '_divide_and_round', '_format_offset', 
'_format_time', '_is_leap', '_isoweek1monday', '_math', '_ord2ymd', '_parse_hh_mm_ss_ff', '_parse_isoformat_date', 
'_parse_isoformat_time', '_time', '_time_class', '_tzinfo_class', '_wrap_strftime', '_ymd2ord', 'date', 'datetime', 
'sys', 'time', 'timedelta', 'timezone', 'tzinfo']
```

and I noticed 2 things, one is that the private functions are showing and also that the attribute "datetime_CAPI" does not exist. Which explains why it shows that error.
I did the same check on the PC I'm using to build Python and I get:

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dir(dt)
['MAXYEAR', 'MINYEAR', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', 
'__package__', '__spec__', 'date', 'datetime', 'datetime_CAPI', 'sys', 'time', 'timedelta', 'timezone', 'tzinfo']
```

Checking that "datetime_CAPI_ attribute shows:

```
>>> dt.datetime_CAPI
<capsule object "datetime.datetime_CAPI" at 0x7f58e6242720>
```

It seems to be somekind of object used to call a C function from Python.
But why is it missing?

Comment: "the private functions are showing"—Python doesn't have "private functions". The leading underscore is just a convention.

Comment: It would appear that `datetime_CAPI` is only available on some systems, perhaps there's some compiler directive that leaves it out in a build for ARM because some component it would rely on would be missing on that platform. You may need to look into ways of rebuilding numpy for your platform so that it no longer has that dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was a Python compilation issue. I used the following commands to compile Python and the problem was solved.

```
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc CXX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ AR=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ar \
    RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabihf-ranlib \
    ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=$HOME/python3.8.10 \
    --disable-ipv6 ac_cv_file__dev_ptmx=no ac_cv_file__dev_ptc=no \
    ac_cv_have_long_long_format=yes --enable-shared

make HOSTPYTHON=$HOME/python3.8.10 \
    BLDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared" CROSS-COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
    CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes HOSTARCH=arm-linux BUILDARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf

make altinstall HOSTPYTHON=$HOME/python3.8.10 \
    BLDSHARED="arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -shared" CROSS-COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- \
    CROSS_COMPILE_TARGET=yes HOSTARCH=arm-linux BUILDARCH=arm-linux-gnueabihf \
    prefix=$HOME/python3.8.10/_install
```